# How to add model name suffix for EF Core scaffold db?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, command-line-interface, file-rename

Is it possible for me to tell the command `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to add a suffix of `Entity` to all the models it makes?

Use case, I have a table called `Users`. I want EF Core to create a model called `UsersEntity`. Is this possible with a flag or am I going to have to do something like [this](https://www.scaledeskit.net/post/Windows-CMD-Add-Suffix-to-all-files-in-folder) + mass string replace in all the .cs files?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this? It's pretty redundant and only serves to make your code less readable.

Comment: @DavidG The reason is it's our standard. So, can it be done with the dotnet ef core cli?

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: @DavidG latest, 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I am trying do the same thing.

My plan is to use the Entity Framework Core templates to add a suffix to all my entities when scaffolding.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli for instructions about how to setup the template.